# Can jquery and perl mason work in this way?

Tags: jquery, perl

Try to write jquery like below, ( I put a perl mason <% $groupname %> in).

```
$(".inputform").html('GroupName: <input type="text" name="query" value="<% $groupname %>"><input type="submit" name="action">');
```

My intention is in the 'form', I will use perl mason to check the groupname. But it looks below codes not working.

```
<form class="inputform", method="post".....>

%if($groupname eq 'blahblah') {
%    #other perl codes 
%}

</form>
```

Any hint is appreciated.

Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, changing a document in your browser is not going to execute any Perl/Mason code on another machine. You would need to send some kind of request to that machine. AJAX is normally used to do this.

Alternatively, you could have the Perl/Mason script generate code to create a JavaScript variable containing a list of all valid groups (assuming the size of the list allows for this) along with the form. That way, the group names would be available to the client without contacting the server.

Comment: 'groupname' is supposedly an 'input'. I'd like to pick the input into mason to interpret it. I'm not quite understanding the alternative way you mentioned. could you please give more hints? Thanks.

Comment: This is for form input validation, right? Well, I don't know JavaScript enough off the top of my head, but if you have had a small number of groups, you could generate the code `<script>var groupnames = ...;...</script>` in the HTML and include a JS validation function that uses that variable.

Comment: En, you are right. I have changed the way to AJAX. Thanks, your suggestions do open my mind. Thanks a lot.